# remove links from images using functions.php

Tags: functions, images, attachments, links

I am looking for a way to remove the attachment link from images in the post content.

I would like to add this to the functions.php in  my theme. I know you can disable this in the post on a per image basis, but I would like to do this just once in my functions.php page. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}
```

The regex could be simpler and unfortunately this also deprives you of the unique `wp-image-xxx` (where *xxx* is the attachment ID) class of the `<img>` tag, but it's the safest one I could come up with to **only** remove links around attachment images and leave in-text links as well as links around non-attachment images intact.

If you don't care about non-attachment images and want all images within the post content to not be wrapped in links anyway, this should suffice:

```
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'), array('<img','/>'), $content);
    return $content;
}
```

I can see it breaking things though, if the inside of an anchor ends in some other self-closing element, such as a `<br />` tag. That would be rare, obviously, but I'd recommend using the first, though longer version.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect! I ended up using the first one and yes this saved me a lot of time.