# Remove link from post images

Tags: post-thumbnails

When Upload images from Editor and publish the post, I see for all images have link. 
How can remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. The filter will check for images and removes the a (link) tag. Just add it to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
 function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
  $content =
  preg_replace(
  array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
  '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
  array('<img','" />'),
  $content
  );
  return $content;
   }
```

Comment: So you copied the code from the answer I suggested. Please don't do that, because generally duplicate content should be prevented.

Comment: Since I'm not allowed to simply post links to other content, I think this is the most proper anwser to the question. Better then none anwserd questions if you ask me.

Comment: You can post links in comments, if you are not able yet earn some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution and it seemed to work but on viewing the source code I found stray link closing tags: `</a>`

I found this solution which works:

```
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter($content) {
    $content = 
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a[^>]*><img}', '{/></a>}'),
            array('<img', '/>'), 
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter');
```

Thanks to @noman for answering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814468/regex-to-remove-links-surrounding-images)

Answer (score 0):

When inserting the image via the »Media Library« Modal, after clicking »Add Media«, select »None« for »Link To« under »Attachment Display Settings« section. To remove it for already linked images, click on the image and then press the »Remove link« button.

Comment: ok, But old post how delete url for it ?

Comment: see 2nd part of the answer @KotshMan

Comment: But i have more than 2000 post !!!

Comment: Brief outline: loop through posts (content) regex for `img` tags inside `a` tags and remove the `a` tags. Take a look around, there have been similar questions asked before. @KotshMan

Comment: how can do that ?? so that is reson to post my question

Comment: Take a look for example at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33749/22534). Aside from that, like I said, this has been answered before, so search for it. @KotshMan